# How can I compare distinct vs duplicate values in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Name    Wage    Year
John    25,000  2016
John    35,000  2016
John    50,000  2015
Paul    70,000  2015
Paul    72,000  2016
George  50,000  2015
George  50,000  2016
```

Say I have the above SQL table, how do I compare the average wage of individuals that only have one wage in a year versus those who have multiple wages? E.g. In 2016 do people with one wage earn more than those with two or vice versa?

I'm trying to write a query of people that only occur once in a year vs. those that appear more than once and compare the average wage of the two groups.

The result I would like is:

```
single_wage_average     multiple_wage_average     Year
50,000                  61,000                    2016
```

Comment: Post (add to your question) the desired result.

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all these using average and count as below:

```
select *, AverageWage = avg(wage) over(partition by name, [year]), 
    [CountOfOneWage]=count(name) over(partition by name, [year]) from #yourwage
order by name
```

With this query you can get the required output.

Your input table:

```
create table #yourwage (name varchar(20), wage money, year int)

insert into #yourwage 
( Name   ,  Wage  ,  [Year]  ) values
 ('John',    25000 , 2016   )
,('John',    35000 , 2016   )
,('John',    50000 , 2015   )
,('Paul',    70000 , 2015   )
,('Paul',    72000 , 2016   )
,('George',  50000 , 2015   )
,('George',  50000 , 2016   )
```

Comment: Not exactly what  I had in mind but this will get me there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with aggregation:

```
select name, year, avg(wage) as avg_wage, count(*) as num
from t
group by name, year;
```

Then you can aggregate again:

```
select year,
       avg(case when num = 1 then avg_wage end) as singleton_avg,
       avg(case when num > 1 then avg_wage end) as duplicate_avg
from (select name, year, avg(wage) as avg_wage, count(*) as num
      from t
      group by name, year
     ) ny
group by year;
```

Comment: An anonymous downvote is very curious on what seems like a correct answer.